# How to check If the system Date is 30 days back

Tags: java, datetime

How to check in java whether the   system Date is 30 days back

Means for example if today is May 26 then if i pass April 26 , it should tell that this is of Last Month Data

```
If(SystemDate-30)
```

Comment: what prevents you from doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(startDate);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -30);
cal.set(HOUR, 0);
cal.set(MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(SECOND, 0);
cal.set(MILLISECOND, 0);
Date dateBefore30DayFromStartDate = cal.getDate();
```

Now you can compare

Answer (score 2):

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html#datediff